# show div onscroll but hide div onclick permanently

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, display

I've got a div, that fades in on scroll. The problem is, even if I onclick hide it, its going to fade in again on scroll. How to hide it permanently if someone clicks the closing "X"?   https://jsfiddle.net/y9txx3tn/

Also I would like to add some sliding effect to show different text. Therefore I would like to use the bootstrap slider. The problem is, I allready have one and out of some reason its not sliding although I change the id.

```
    <div id="bewertung">
        <div id="carousel-bounding-box">
        <a href="#" class="close-thik" onclick="document.getElementById('bewertung').style.display='none';return false;"></a>   
            <div id="slidebewertung" class="carousel slide">
                <!-- main slider carousel items -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="active item" data-slide-number="0">
                        <strong>Sven</strong> <br>
                        <small>Head of Marketing Göpel GmbH</small><br>
                        <img src="./bilder/erfahrung-bm-translations.JPG" /><br>
                        <em>sdfsdeit</em>             
                    </div>
                    <div class="item" data-slide-number="1">
                        <strong>Sven</strong> <br>
                        <small>Head of Marketing Göpel GmbH</small><br>
                        <img src="./bilder/erfahrung-bm-translations.JPG" /><br>
                        <em>sdfsdfhkeit</em>                                          
                    </div>  
                    <div class="item" data-slide-number="2">
                        <strong>Sven </strong> <br>
                        <small>Head of Marketing Göpel GmbH</small><br>
                        <img src="./bilder/erfahrung-bm-translations.JPG" /><br>
                        <em>Frsdfdsfhkeit</em>                                        
                    </div>  
                    <div class="item" data-slide-number="3">
                        <strong>Sven </strong> <br>
                        <small>Head of Marketing Göpel GmbH</small><br>
                        <img src="./bilder/erfahrung-bm-translations.JPG" /><br>
                        <em>Freusdfsdfsdff</em>
                    </div>                      
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#bewertung{
        width: 140px;
        bottom: 0;
        float: right;
        left: 0;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 99;
        background: white;
        border: 1px solid grey;
        border-radius: 10px;
        padding: 1%;
        font-size: 11px;
    }

    [class*='close-'] {
      color: #777;
      font: 14px/100% arial, sans-serif;
      position: absolute;
      right: 5px;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
      top: 5px;
    }

    .close-thik:after {
      content: '✖'; /* UTF-8 symbol */
    }
```

Javascript

```
$("#bewertung").hide();
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 250) {
        $("#bewertung").fadeIn("slow");
        $('#slidebewertung').carousel({
            interval: 8000
        });
    }
    else {
        $("#bewertung").fadeOut("fast");
    }
});
```

Comment: When the div is hidden, also detach the scroll handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a "flag" to remember the closed state.

I removed the inline `onclick()` to have it in script.
Easyer to read.

Then, I added `bewertungClosed=true` to it.
This will prevent the `fadeIn()` on scroll.

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/1229d4th/)

```js
$("#bewertung").hide();
var bewertungClosed=false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50 && !bewertungClosed) {
    $("#bewertung").fadeIn("slow");
  }
  else {
    $("#bewertung").fadeOut("fast");
  }
});

$(".close-thik").on("click",function(){
  document.getElementById('bewertung').style.display='none';
  bewertungClosed=true;
  return false;
});
```

```css
#bewertung{
  width: 140px;
  bottom: 0;
  float: right;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 1%;
  font-size: 11px;
}

[class*='close-'] {
  color: #777;
  font: 14px/100% arial, sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
  top: 5px;
}

.close-thik:after {
  content: '✖'; /* UTF-8 symbol */
}
```

```html
<head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script></head>

<div id="bewertung">
  <div id="carousel-bounding-box">
    <a href="#" class="close-thik"></a>   
    <div id="slidebewertung" class="carousel slide">
      <!-- main slider carousel items -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="active item" data-slide-number="0">
          <strong>Sven</strong> <br>
          <small>Head of Marketing Göpel GmbH</small><br>
          <img src="./bilder/erfahrung-bm-translations.JPG" /><br>
          <em>sdfsdeit</em>             
        </div>
        <div class="item" data-slide-number="1">
          <strong>Sven</strong> <br>
          <small>Head of Marketing Göpel GmbH</small><br>
          <img src="./bilder/erfahrung-bm-translations.JPG" /><br>
          <em>sdfsdfhkeit</em>                                          
        </div>  
        <div class="item" data-slide-number="2">
          <strong>Sven </strong> <br>
          <small>Head of Marketing Göpel GmbH</small><br>
          <img src="./bilder/erfahrung-bm-translations.JPG" /><br>
          <em>Frsdfdsfhkeit</em>                                        
        </div>  
        <div class="item" data-slide-number="3">
          <strong>Sven </strong> <br>
          <small>Head of Marketing Göpel GmbH</small><br>
          <img src="./bilder/erfahrung-bm-translations.JPG" /><br>
          <em>Freusdfsdfsdff</em>
        </div>                      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p><p>. </p>
```

Comment: thats working perfectly, thank you very much! Do you have any idea, how to make the carousel working?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to detach the scroll handler when the bewertung DIV is hidden.

Try this :

```
var $bewertung = $("#bewertung").hide();

$(window).on('scroll.bewartung', function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
        $bewertung.fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
        $bewertung.fadeOut('fast');
    }
}).find("a.close-thik").on('click', function() {
    $bewertung.hide();
    $(window).off('scroll.bewartung');
    return false;
});
```

And remove that `onclick` handler from the HTML.